# How to solve ErrorException in PaymentHelper.php line 316: Division by zero in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

code:

```
$result['rooms_price'] = round($result['total_night_price'] / $total_nights);
```

I am simply doing calculation but I had got an error i.e. Division by zero. Please tell me how can I resolve and what does it mean.

Thank You

Comment: Check your value for $total_nights, is there scenarios where that is being set to zero?

Comment: it show nothing look at once `$from = new DateTime($checkin);
        $to = new DateTime($checkout);
        $total_nights = $to->diff($from)->format("%a");` @Devasta